# Not getting proper result but working in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

This is the code that is already working in mysql database but I want to convert it into **Laravel 5.6**

```sql
    SELECT * 
    FROM `listings` 
    WHERE (
    country_id=1 
    AND (state=32 or city=8) 
    AND (listing_id LIKE "%6562%" OR title LIKE "%6562%"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you have a model called `Listing` which takes care of the `listings` table. You can write the query like this:

```php
$listings = App\Listing::where('field1', 1)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('field2', 32);
        $query->orWhere('field3', 8);
     })
     ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('field4', 'LIKE', '%6562%');
        $query->orWhere('field5', 'LIKE', '%6562%');
     })
     ->get();
```

The first parameter of the `where` method can be a callback which can achieve this type of grouping (field2=32 or field3=8)

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I have written as below-
$listings = App\Listing::where('field1', 1)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('field2', 32);
        $query->orWhere('field3', 8);
     })
     ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('field4', 'LIKE', '%6562%');
        $query->orWhere('field5', 'LIKE', '%6562%');
     })
     ->get();
but not getting proper result. It must be return field1 and either field2 or field3 and either field4 or field5

Comment: $lst = listing::whereRaw('find_in_set(?,country_id)',[$cid])                                
                ->where(function ($lst) use($location){                
                    $lst->orWhere('state','=',$location);
                    $lst->orWhere('city','=',$location);                
                })
                ->where(function ($lst) use ($keywords){
                $lst->where('title','LIKE','%'.$keywords.'%');
                $lst->orWhere('listing_id','LIKE','%'.$keywords.'%');
                })            
                ->paginate(20);

Comment: Getting blank or null as result